# Android: Using PopupMenu in API level 9

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, popupmenu

I like to add a PopupMenu to my application. The problem is that it should work on Android 2.3, too.
I found some posts where people suggest to use AlertDialog as an alternative, but I prefer a PopupMenu ;)

I think it should work in this API-level, too because I've seen it in several apps (my phone has 2.3.5 and it work fine).

Is there any possibility to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PopupMenu is possible you can try this in a method for sending an email and you can inflate your xml according to your own needs:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)EEActionListDetail.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    int width = display.getWidth()/2;
    int height = display.getHeight()/2;

    View pop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupemail,null,false);
    pop.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    height = pop.getMeasuredHeight();
    width = pop.getMeasuredWidth()+200;
    pu = new PopupWindow(pop,width,height,true);
    pu.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.ll3),Gravity.CENTER,1,1);

    Button brnSend = (Button)pu.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    Button close = (Button)pu.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.close);

    Subject = (EditText)pu.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.subject);
    Message = (EditText)pu.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.message);

    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pu.dismiss();

        }
    });
    brnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int j=0;j<EmailArray.size();j++){
                String EmailSent = EmailArray.get(j);
                SendEmailALL(EmailSent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 13):

- You must import support v7 in your application same as follow: [Adding libraries with resources](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)
- `import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;`
- Compile your code with that and then your popup menu is compatible for android 2.2 and above.

Comment: I knew it... funny thing is I tried that before... maybe I got a typo back then... now it works like a charm xD